# Laptop video card failure symptoms

Tags: laptop, video, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I have a Toshiba Satellite P200. Recently, video output started behaving erratically.
At first, while playing flash video, whole image would tremble and then freeze with only cursor left moving. Reboot would usually fix it. Then, at reboot, red squares of four red dots would appear on the logo page. In GRUB and while linux kernel was loading, double exclamation marks would appear all over the screen. And now, linux won't even start anything graphic (e.g. KDE), let alone 3D. Vista would first complain about the video driver crashing, now it won't even start in normal mode, only in safe mode. BIOS screen is normal. I can still type in console, although a wrong symbol would appear for almost each symbol typed. Exclamation points won't go away and console outputs are garbled.

My suspicion is there's something wrong with the video chip, but I am asking you could there be something else at fault? Like a specific capacitor, resistor, eprom?

Video card is GeForce Go 7600.

Answer (score 1):

Video artifacts are usually caused by damaged video RAM.

Since it happens in during the BIOS boot logo, it's definitely a hardware issue.

I'm not sure if your GeForce Go 7600 is an integrated video adapter or not, but unless you have spare compatible system SO-DIMM RAM or a Toshiba GeForce Go 7600 adapter laying around you're going to have to take it to someone who does.

If you check with [Toshiba's support web page](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/globalEntitlement.jsp), you can determine your warranty status, and find an official Toshiba repair depot (read: independent computer shops that are certified by Toshiba) near you.

HTH :)